# How is my android application running on 2.2 ADT with a 4.4 build target

Tags: android, android-actionbar, adt, android-appcompat

I'm trying to figure out how versioning works on android. I've been trying to get appcompat running on my application so I can add an action bar. So I was importing the v7 support library and using android.jar build target 2.2. I eventually switched to 4.4 and that worked for me and my application was still able to launch in my 2.2 ADT

2 questions.

Is it possible to run appcompat on android.jar build target 2.2 or do i have to use a target SDK later than 3.0?

My second question is how is it possible for android.jar build target 4.4 to run on a 2.2 ADT?

Comment: Target the highest API level you can. That means for the higher API levels you can use more API's.